# Decoding of QR code using Google Chart API

Tags: android

I am making an app in which i have to encode and decode text into QR code. I have encoded the text using google chart API
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=50x50&cht=qr&chl=abcdef".

If someone can help me how to decode QR Bitmap image again into text using Google Chart API

Answer (score 1):

That's not what the charts API is designed to do. You need to use a barcode reader like ZXing. If you look at the project wiki there are examples on what intents to use to make it work and return you the correct text.

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/